# Regular expression for format XXXXXXX_YZZZZ

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression in java which will validate following format-

```
XXXXXXXX_YZZZZ
```

where

```
X – alphanumeric characters(8 characters)
Y - alpha character
Z - numeric characters
```

what I have tried for first part is - `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$` but I am not getting how to go for second part.

Can any one tell me what will be the correct regex for required format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}[_][a-zA-Z][0-9]{4}$
```

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to specify the amount and the underscore I assume...

```
/^[a-z0-9]{8}_[a-z][0-9]{4}$/i
```

Comment: Yea, sorry. :) They're in now

Comment: What does the `^` and `$` do?

Comment: Ash Burlaczenko, `^` indicates starts with and `$` indicates ends with

Comment: @nhahtdh then what regex is this??

Comment: @Vivek: If you remove the delimiters `/`, and set the `i` flag with Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE, or embed `(?i)` in front of the string, then it will become Java regex. The content is the same, but the presentation is different.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), then you can translate your requirements to:

```
"^\\p{Alnum}{8}_\\p{Alpha}\\p{Digit}{4}$"
```

It uses predefined character classes, like you listed in your question.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
^[a-ZA-Z0-9]{8}\_[a-zA-Z][0-9]{4}$
```

You can also group the results:

```
^([a-ZA-Z0-9]{8})\_([a-zA-Z])([0-9]{4})$
```

so that you can address the X, Y and Z parts individually from the results.

Comment: What's the need of escaping `_`?

Comment: It's not really needed, no, but I like to escape literals because that makes the regex clearer (at least for me).

Comment: But it would be better to avoid unwanted escaping.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
^[A-Za-z\d]{8}_[A-Za-z]\d{4}$
```

Your regex matches zero or more alphanumeric characters and/or whitespaces.

This is a good place to learn regex : http://www.regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}_[a-zA-Z][0-9]{4}$
```

[Regexper](http://www.regexper.com/) is your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}_[a-zA-Z][0-9]{4}$
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can use metacharacters to express regulars expressions :

```
    "8abba778_a2012".matches("^\\w{8}_[a-z]\\d{4}$");
```

[EDIT] : According @Jon Dvorak, I am correcting my answer. In fact, \w is too generous and also applies to the underscore character _. The correct answer :

```
     "8abba778_a2012".matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}_[a-z]\\d{4}$");
```

Comment: Well according to Javadoc, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html, \w is equivalent to [a-zA-Z_0-9]. I dont understant why?

Comment: `\\w` is too generous because it tolerates an underscore.

Comment: Well, \w,\d,\s are called metacharacters generally. Or should I say predefined character classes in Java terms.